# Building Addins using common environment for ArcGIS 10.4 and 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.4, visual-studio, arcobjects

I have an addin for ArcGis 10.0. This addin is developed in following environment:

- Visual studio 2010 ,
- ArcObjects sdk for 10.0 (arcgis)

When I want to use same addin on ArcGis 10.4 version, it does not work. Then I build
my code on :

- Visual studio 2015 community edition,
- ArcObjects sdk for 10.4 (arcgis)

and it works fine.

Now, I want to know, is there any common environment where I build my code and run in both version of arcgis (10.4 and 10.0)?

Comment: I always thought addins were upwardly compatible? Did you change which version of .net you compiled against? I have am addin compiled for arcgis 10.2, it definitely works on 10.4.1

Comment: "When I want to use same addin on ArcGis 10.4 version, it does not work" - what doesn't work?  It won't load to ArcMap, or it gives errors when you try to run it, or it just doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Midavalo, in arcmap 10.4 , it won't load.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 is in Retired status.  Compatibility across four releases is quite a stretch.  Rather than setting that as your goal, why not use a code repository with two build environments.

Comment: thanks @Vince, Now I am doing so. If there is a common environment, it will be helpful. I have to support my addin software in both 10.0 and 10.4

Comment: Keep in mind that Microsoft changed their compilers three times as well. There is no simple solution here.